# change boot disk with virtual pc xp on win7

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have got a project i did on a virtual drive using Virtual PC with win xp on. I did this on my computer with win7. Now i want to open the virtual xp but it just won't work. i create a new virtual pc and i go into the file called Windows XP Mode 1 and the file type is a virtual machine shell information file. I go into the settings and i try to change the disk where it will start from so that it will start with my old disk. But ive got all kinds of problems that i can't find the parent disk and so on. Can anyone explain to me how to ge my virtual pc to use my old projects virtual machine hard drive image disk?

Comment: If i say it like this:
Ive got a file called Windows XP Mode 1 and it is a virtual machine hard drive image typ, how do i open it?

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is off-topic for StackOverflow according to the [help] guidelines. I'm voting to move it to [su] where it's more appropriate. Good luck.